# Shotwell uses the correct date in events but the wrong one in the Pictures folder

Tags: shotwell

I am currently using Shotwell 0.9.3 as my main photo organizer and I noticed that there is some sort of error when I import photos (usually from an SD card).

What I do is I choose *File » Import From Folder...* and then I select my SD card and click *Copy Photos* on the dialog box. The photos are imported to the correct event, say the pictures were taken on Jan 01, 2012 and so the photos are shown under Jan 01, 2012.

What puzzles me is that when I check under `~/Pictures`, I couldn't find the imported pictures in folder `~/Pictures/2012/01/01` but instead I find them under `~/Pictures/2011/12/31` which is a day earlier than when the picture was taken.

Is this a bug?

Thanks.

Comment: That's not the expected behavior. Have you changed any of the default settings? And, can you check the EXIF info from the photos themselves? (do this in Nautilus, right-click/Properties) See if the camera time is set correctly.

Comment: Yes, I have checked the EXIF info and they are correct. I did not change any settings so they are still in default. I am using Thunar in place of Nautilus and right-click/Properties reveal that the photo was taken on Jan 01, 2012 (and not Dec 31, 2011) as per my example above.

Comment: Strange, sounds like a bug. Try filing a report: http://redmine.yorba.org/projects/shotwell/wiki/ShotwellFAQ#I-found-a-bug-in-Shotwell-How-can-I-report-it

Answer (score 3):

This was a known issue and was fixed in Shotwell 0.11.

Bug report is here: 
http://redmine.yorba.org/issues/3427